# Javascript Regular expression range with exceptions

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, regex, ajax

**my current regex**

```
...
var my_var = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$')
...
```

this selects characters  `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, and **space*   and eliminate the rest

but, I want to select..  ' `(` ', ' `)` ' and ' `-` ' too, so how to make exceptions.

Comment: What does "make exceptions" mean? You can add both those characters to the set in your existing expression.

Comment: sorry, i meant i want to add these '(-)' to the range

Comment: Well maybe add `(`, `)`, and `-` to the `[ ]` range. Put the `-` at the very end.

Comment: @Pointy yeah i tried, error "Invalid regular expression: /^[a-zA-Z0-9()- ]+$/: Range out of order in character class" but it works as `RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9() ]+$')`

Comment: Put the `-` as the very last character in the `[ ]` set, or else use `\-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This Worked** (adding `-` in the end)

```
var my_var = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9() -]+$')
```

*refer @Pointy 's comments for reference*